# Mysql count with multiple left join

Tags: mysql, count, null, left-join

I'm really having trouble with mysql query to retrieve records with counts. Here's the scenario. I would like to get master table (criteria) rows with students count who are not present in selected_students table.

```
criteria
---------
id  name
1   maths
2   medicine
3   physics

criteria_matches
------------------
id  criteria_ref_id   user_ref_id
1          1            153
2          1            222
3          1            699
4          2            486
5          2            38
6          3            141

selected_students
-----------------
id  user_ref_id  selected_by  status
1        153        15     'E'
2        500        15     'E'
3        486        15     'E'
3        141        15     'E'



expected result
----------------
criteria_id criteria_name   student_count
1               maths       2
2               medicine    1
3               physics     0
```

I tried with the below query to get the parent table rows with counts but no luck

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(DISTINCT ss.user_ref_id) AS students_count FROM criteria t  
LEFT JOIN criteria_matches cm ON cm.criteria_ref_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN selected_students ss ON ss.user_ref_id = cm.user_ref_id
WHERE dss.user_ref_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY t.name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to count `user_ref_id` from the `criteria_matches` table, not from `selected_students` (due to the filter in your `WHERE` clause*, the latter will always be `NULL` and therefore a `COUNT()` thereof will always be 0):

```
SELECT   t.id, t.name, COUNT(DISTINCT cm.user_ref_id) AS students_count
FROM     criteria t  
  LEFT JOIN criteria_matches  cm ON cm.criteria_ref_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN selected_students ss ON ss.user_ref_id     = cm.user_ref_id
WHERE    ss.user_ref_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.name
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45611/1/0).

---

<sup>* NB: the `WHERE` clause in your question erroneously references the undefined table alias `dss`.  I assume you meant to reference the `ss` alias of the `selected_students` table.</sup>

Comment: Oh no, i just edited the fiddle the script and results are not including all the maste table rows . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c70e6/1

Comment: @sam: You either need to include the filter condition that `ss.user_ref_id IS NULL` [within the outer join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c70e6/10/0) on the `criteria` table; or else [refactor](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c70e6/16/0) to use a (less efficient, but clearer) subquery.

Comment: Thank you, i will use the outer join